# How to make the converted to GridLength work with GridUnitType.Star?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding, converters

I get an error trying to convert double to GridLength in star units. The converted itself works fine but I get an error in the runtime

> "System.ArgumentException: NaN is not a valid value for width\n  at Xamarin.Forms.Size..ctor (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x00008] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Size.cs:19 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.ContractColumnsIfNeeded (System.Double width, System.Func`2[T,TResult] predicate) [0x00075] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:213 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.MeasureAndContractStarredColumns (System.Double width, System.Double height, System.Double totalStarsWidth) [0x000bb] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:397 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.MeasureGrid (System.Double width, System.Double height, System.Boolean requestSize) [0x0010e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:509 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.OnSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x0002a] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:58 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnMeasure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\
>   \1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:641 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.GetSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00053] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:523 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.GetSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:131 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Measure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint, Xamarin.Forms.MeasureFlags flags) [0x00054] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:581 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.MeasureStarredRows () [0x000c3] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:548 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.MeasureAndContractStarredRows (System.Double width, System.Double height, System.Double totalStarsHeight) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:403 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.MeasureGrid (System.Double width, System.Double height, System.Boolean requestSize) [0x0011
>   7] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:510 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.OnSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x0002a] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:58 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnMeasure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:641 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.GetSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00053] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:523 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.GetSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:131 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Measure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint, Xamarin.Forms.MeasureFlags flags) [0x00054] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:581 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.CalculateNaiveLayout (Xamarin.Forms.Stac
>   kLayout+LayoutInformation layout, Xamarin.Forms.StackOrientation orientation, System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x000a8] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\StackLayout.cs:163 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.CalculateLayout (Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout+LayoutInformation layout, System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint, System.Boolean processExpanders) [0x00058] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\StackLayout.cs:123 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.OnSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00019] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\StackLayout.cs:80 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnMeasure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:641 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.GetSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00053] in D:\a\1\
>   s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:523 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.GetSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:131 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Measure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint, Xamarin.Forms.MeasureFlags flags) [0x00054] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:581 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.CalculateAutoCells (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x000e5] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:131 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.MeasureGrid (System.Double width, System.Double height, System.Boolean requestSize) [0x0000c] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:483 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.OnSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x0002a] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:58 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnMeasure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000]
>    in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:641 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.GetSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00053] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:523 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.GetSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:131 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Measure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint, Xamarin.Forms.MeasureFlags flags) [0x00054] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:581 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView.OnSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x0005d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ScrollView.cs:233 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnMeasure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:641 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.GetSizeRequest (System.Dou
>   ble widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00053] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:523 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.GetSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:131 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Measure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint, Xamarin.Forms.MeasureFlags flags) [0x00054] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:581 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.CalculateNaiveLayout (Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout+LayoutInformation layout, Xamarin.Forms.StackOrientation orientation, System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x000a8] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\StackLayout.cs:163 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.CalculateLayout (Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout+LayoutInformation layout, System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint, System.Boolean pro
>   cessExpanders) [0x00058] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\StackLayout.cs:123 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x0005b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\StackLayout.cs:57 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout () [0x0014b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:263 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x0000f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:223 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:679 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x00021] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:908 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) [0x0005d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:186 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.L
>   ayout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:565 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region) [0x001da] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:177 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x0010d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:187 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.UpdateChildrenLayout () [0x000c6] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:259 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x0000f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:240 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:679 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x00021] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualEleme
>   nt.cs:908 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) [0x0005d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:186 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:565 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region) [0x0005f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:146 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x0010d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:187 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.UpdateChildrenLayout () [0x000c6] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:259 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x0000f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:240 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x00000] in D:\a\
>   1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:679 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x00021] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:908 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) [0x0005d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:186 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:565 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region) [0x0005f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:146 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x0010d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:187 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.UpdateChildrenLayout () [0x000c6] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:259 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, Sy
>   stem.Double height) [0x0000f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:240 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:679 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x00021] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:908 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) [0x0005d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:186 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:565 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region) [0x0005f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:146 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.LayoutChildren (System.Double x, System.Double y, System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x00103] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.C
>   ore\Page.cs:185 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.UpdateChildrenLayout () [0x000c6] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:259 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnSizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x0000f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:240 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:679 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x00021] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:908 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value) [0x0005d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:186 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout (Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle bounds) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:565 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.ViewDidLayoutSubviews () [0x00172] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\NavigationRe
>   nderer.cs:182 \n  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)\n  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.4.0.64/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 \n  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.4.0.64/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 \n  at PrenCare.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00002] in C:\Users\ondre\source\repos\PrenCare\src\Version02\PrenCare\PrenCare.iOS\Main.cs:19 "

. The strange thing is the converter works perfectly when I use the Absolute unit.

**Converter**

```
public class NumberToGridLengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is double numberValue))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Type {value.GetType().FullName} cannot be converted to GridLenght");
        }

        return new GridLength(numberValue, GridUnitType.Star); // Star makes it crash
        //return GridLength.Star; // Star makes it crash as well
        //return new GridLength(numberValue); // This works fine

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is GridLength gridLength))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Type {value.GetType().FullName} is not GridLenght");
        }

        return gridLength.Value;
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <conv:NumberToGridLengthConverter x:Key="numberToGridLengthConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>  
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" ColumnSpacing="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=MovementCalm, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource numberToGridLengthConverter}}" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=MovementRapid, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource numberToGridLengthConverter}}" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <BoxView Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="20" />
            <BoxView Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Orange" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="20" />
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class StatisticsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private double _movementCalm;
    public double MovementCalm
    {
        get => _movementCalm;
        set => SetProperty(ref _movementCalm, value);
    }

    private double _movementRapid;
    public double MovementRapid
    {
        get => _movementRapid;
        set => SetProperty(ref _movementRapid, value);
    }

    public StatisticsViewModel()
    {
    }

    public override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        SetMovement();
    }

    private void SetMovement()
    {
        MovementCalm = 90f;
        MovementRapid = 10f;
    }
}


public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public virtual void OnAppearing()
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnDisappearing()
    {
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(
        ref T backingStore,
        T value,
        [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Any idea how to make it work with Star units?

Comment: "I get an error in the runtime' - what is the specific error, and which line causes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you set the `GridUnitType` to `Star`, the width of `Column` will never change (each `Column` will take up 1/2 of the screen if you have 2 `Columns`).

```
//
// Summary:
//     Interpret the Xamarin.Forms.GridLength.Value property value as a proportional
//     weight, to be laid out after rows and columns with Xamarin.Forms.GridUnitType.Absolute
//     or Xamarin.Forms.GridUnitType.Auto are accounted for.
//
// Remarks:
//     After all the rows and columns of type Xamarin.Forms.GridUnitType.Absolute and
//     Xamarin.Forms.GridUnitType.Auto are laid out, each of the corresponding remaining
//     rows or columns, which are of type Xamarin.Forms.GridUnitType.Star, receive a
//     fraction of the remaining available space. This fraction is determined by dividing
//     each row's or column's Xamarin.Forms.GridLength.Value property value by the sum
//     of all the row or column Xamarin.Forms.GridLength.Value property values, correspondingly,
//     including its own.
Star = 1,
```

In addition, when you set the `Binding Path`, you have to set the `BindingContext` at the same time.

For example, I am binding the value of width to a slider.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
  <StackLayout>
     <Slider x:Name="slider" Maximum="200" Minimum="100" Value="100" />

     <Grid  Grid.Column="1" ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition BindingContext="{x:Reference slider}"  Width="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource numberToGridLengthConverter}}" />
             <ColumnDefinition BindingContext="{x:Reference slider}"  Width="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource numberToGridLengthConverter}}" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <BoxView Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="20" />
        <BoxView Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Orange" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="20" />
    </Grid>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Setting the `GridUnitType` to `Star` will not lead to a crash. So if your issue is still appearing, you can create a sample which contains the issue, so that I can test it on my side .

## **Update:**

I have found your issue!

You should Initialize the **MovementCalm** and **MovementRapid** in the the constructor .

```
public StatisticsViewModel()
{
  SetMovement();
}
```

in your contentpage (such as MainPage)

```
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  BindingContext = new StatisticsViewModel();
}
```

The method **OnAppearing** and **OnDisappearing** will never been called because the ViewModel is not a **ContentPage** .

So the value of width is always **0** .When set the **GridUnitType** as **Star** it will crash . But when you set it as **Absolute** it won't because  Absolute allows value as **0** .

Comment: Well, regarding the first point, it isn't true. Before I implemented the binding, the Width was set to "60*" and "40*" which caused the grid to adjust the width to 60% and 40%.
To the other point, the binding context is set to viewmodel in the first parent tag and all the other bindings work. Actually this binding works too, I can catch the breakpoint in the converter and the value from the viewmodel is also taken.
If you want to test it with the star, use the converter in my original post and just return GridLength.Star. I've also tried that and it crashed as well.

Comment: So ,can you provide a sample? It works fine on my side .

Comment: The sample is in the original question. I've updated it with the exception details.

Comment: Can you provide the code of your ViewModel? This error will appear when you set the wrong binding .

Comment: What is BaseViewModel ? You should provide whole code if you don't want to share a sample .

Comment: The binding itself is working OK. The BaseViewModel implements the INotifyPropertyChange. I've added that to the question. The problem is somewhere in the convertion, not the ViewModel.